# Obtaining Confidence Interval for Function of Multiple Model Coefficients in R

Tags: r

I've run a mixed effects Cox model in R (coxme package). In my model, I have variables for sex (male/female) and parenthood (has child/doesn't) with an interaction between the two.

```
model <- coxme(Surv(spell.length, event) ~ sex + parent + sex:parent + (1 | id),...)
```

I'd like plot model coefficients for four groups with confidence intervals: male/no child; female/no child; male/child; female/child.

I was wondering how to do this as the last group is a function of two model variables. Does anyone know you can do this in R please?

Thanks.

### UPDATE:

Sorry, should have given a data example.

```
library(coxme)
set.seed(1000)
df <- data.frame(
    id = 1:1000,
    spell.length = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 50),
    event = ifelse(runif(1000)<=0.8,0,1),
    sex = factor(x = rep(c("male","female"),500)),
    parent = factor(x=ifelse(runif(1000)<=0.5,"child","no child"))
    ) 
coxme(Surv(spell.length,event) ~ sex + parent + sex:parent + (1|id), df)
```

Comment: Could you construct an example we can use? There might be help to be found in the examples at `?coxme` or associated help pages.

Comment: Sorry! Done now.

Comment: I'm no expert at mixed effect modeling, but that random effect (intercept) by `id` don't appear particularly informative, as all `id`s are unique.

Comment: It won't be, but then my real data don't look like this. I'm just interested how you can multiply, sum, divide (etc.) coefficients and obtain confidence intervals for the final value.

Comment: `coxme` has a `predict()` method, is that of use? Also there is a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxme/vignettes/coxme.pdf), in case you didn't know. I can halfway fight my way through `lme4`, but this survival/cox stuff is entirely new to me. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look

Comment: I think the solution is to follow this: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2014q3/022698.html

Comment: Remember that you have the possibility to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That link may die or move, but a short write-up demonstrating how this can be done will stick around and be helpful for other people having a similar question as yours.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some reading online, I think the answer to this is to remember that...

[image]

And that the standard error is just the square root of the variance of an estimator.

[image]

In R you can extract the variance and covariance using the `vcov` function. For instance:

```
data(mtcars)
model <- lm(mpg ~ disp + wt, data=mtcars)
var <- vcov(model)[2,2]+vcov(model)[3,3]+2*vcov(model)[2,3]
se <- sqrt(var)
```